# Should we avoid IN clause in DB2 SQL while retrieving data?

Tags: sql, db2

Is it good practice to get all the data from DB2 table by using only select command not mentioning where clause (IN) ?

I was told to avoid IN clause where I am passing 10 String value in SQL.

Comment: Select without a `where` clause is indeed strange. A `where` clause without `in` operators is fine.

Comment: Why would you avoid doing something that is specified by the SQL standard?

Comment: Just 10 values should be fine... if you were passing in more than 100, I might think about creating a temporary table, and filtering using a `JOIN` or something similar. But either option, the optimizer will probably handle either about the same internally.

Comment: For that matter, DB2 supports CTEs, so you could just use that to generate a virtual table to join against.

Comment: Avoid IN by using what alternative?  Avoid it for what reason?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should avoid using an IN() clause whenever you can use a better alternative. (If you need to know whether some other element is actually better, you'll need to specify an environment, table definitions, data volumes, indexes, the statement being executed, etc. IOW, specify everything necessary for us to know an actual answer to an actual problem.)